# MPMoviePlayerViewController not playing a downloaded file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I've downloaded a file from a webserver, and saved it in my Documents Directory.
I try and pass the url of the file to MPMoviePlayerViewController using

```
initWithContentURL:url];
```

Where the url is created with

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"/var/mobile/Applications/7A21A941-A54C-4116-857D-A34EDEE2F2E8/Documents/lesson.m4v"];
```

However whenever I try to play the video, the MoviePlayer appears for a second, with "loading" then dismisses itself.

Am I doing something wrong with the local file URL?
(The video plays fine when streamed from the webserver)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it is dismissing itself, but you actually are using web url instead of fileUrl. You need to initiate it like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"lesson.m4v"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

and pass this url to your MPMovieController

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem, using 
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
fixed it for me. I think it must have been dismissing itself because of the bad URL.

Answer (score 0):

For local files must use:

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath: somethingPath];
```

For server files can use:

```
[NSURL URLWithString: somethingPath];
```